# Red5 rebroadcast RTMP stream

Tags: video-streaming, rtmp, red5

I have a live RTMP stream coming from a VBrick server and I need to rebroadcast that stream to help save my bandwidth. I just installed Red5 on a Ubuntu 12.10 server but I can't figure out how to configure it to rebroadcast an already-live stream.

Is this even possible with Red5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very possible. If you can consume / view the rtmp stream originating from the vbrick, you can send it to Red5 using ffmpeg using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://your.vbrick.ip/path_to_vbrick_stream -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://your.red5.ip/live/vbrickstream
```

Obviously you can name the stream whatever you like and use any available app on your red5 server; I used "live" which is a default app. If your vbrick stream doesn't have audio, use this command instead:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://your.vbrick.ip/path_to_vbrick_stream -an -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://your.red5.ip/live/vbrickstream
```